# Отсутствует SDK для java и ошибка "the select directory is not a valid home for JDK"

Tags: intellij-idea, sdk, java

Установил intellij idea 2017.2, но при создании проекта в поле "Project SDK" значится надпись "No SDK". Если нажать "New" и указать путь к предварительно скачанному JDK-10.0.1, то вылетает ошибка "the select directory is not a valid home for JDK". Путь такой: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1
На intellij idea 2016 та же проблема. 
Читал про какие-то переменные среды, сделал как в инструкции было (см. на скриншотах).
Так же заметил, что в папке Java теперь нет папки с jre, хотя раньше была (переустанавливал jdk). Но ошибка даже при ее наличии была.
Нужно отдельно поставить jre?
Подскажите, что еще я могу делать не так?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, но на Intellij IDEA 2016.2.5. JDK у меня версии jdk1.8.0_281. Поддерживается ли эта JDK в моей версии IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**10** версия **JDK** не совместима с **intellij idea 2017.2**. Скачай более раннюю версию, например, **jdk 8-9**